Preprocess two different kind of datasets for a machine learning problem
I am working on two health-related datasets. And I use Python.

One tabular dataset (called A) contains patient-level information (by id) and a bunch of other features which I have already transformed and cleaned. This dataset has around 3000 rows. The dataset contains labels (y) for a classification problem.
The other data is a collection of dataframes. Each dataframe represents time-series data on a particular patient (by id also). There are around 1000 dataframes (only 1000 patients have available information on this time-series data).

My methods so far:

For the collection of dataframes, for each dataframe/patient-id, I selected only the mean, median, max, and min for each column. Then transformed the a dataframe into a single row of data: for example: "patient_id", "min_X", "max_X", "median_X", "mean_X" instead of lengthy timestep-level dataframe. Do you think this is a good idea to preserve key information about the time-series data? Otherwise, I think of a machine learning model to select the time-series features but not sure how to do so.
Now, I would have this single dataframe (called B) of patient-level time-series data and want to join it with the first cleaned dataframe (A) but the rows are mismatched. That is, A has 3000 rows but B only has 1000 rows. The patient ids of B are subset of the patient ids of A. I don't know how to deal with this. I'm thinking of just using the 1000 rows of B and left join A but would it be a lot of data loss? Or impute missing rows in B with meaningful values (e.g., overall mean or median) or a separate category for "no time-series data."

Any advice/thoughts are appreciated.
